# Is it possible to use datetime to get an object for date only in C#?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Given that I have a date and only want to display the date and not date and time, how would I go about this?

Here is the code I expect to do this:

```
var day = 4;
var month = 12;
var year = 2016;

DateTime someDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);

Console.WriteLine(someDate.Date.ToString("d"));
```

I purpose this question because there does not seem to be an object that simply shows the date without changing it to a string.

For example,

Using the `someDate.Date` gives the date with 00:00:00 as the time, so

12/4/2016, turns out to be 12/4/2016 00:00:00 from the actual object, how do I just get 12/4/2016 as an object without the 00:00:00?

Comment: I always just used `DateTime.Date`, and when displaying it to users formatted it with `.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`. So, the answer depends on what you actually want to do, and why you want to do it.

Comment: Use the [Date Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to get your desired string representation.

Comment: You can also use the DateTime.ToShortDateString() method

Comment: Here is the dilemma, I do not need to display it, I just need to use the data for searching database. I need date object not a string.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a culture specific date, try using `ToShortDateString`.

Answer (score 1):

> 12/4/2016, turns out to be 12/4/2016 00:00:00 from the actual object,
>   how do I just get 12/4/2016 as an object without the 00:00:00?

I think the best you can do is as below:

```
DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```